# Android: Design for concurrent background jobs (Service, IntentService or AsyncTask?)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-intentservice

I need help designing a solution to a problem specific to long running background tasks.

### Background:

- I have an app with activity that displays a list of files.
- The files can each be downloaded. Each downloaded file can have an update.
- The updates, if any, are fired as notifications with update now button. The app has an activity that shows the updates for each file.
- Clicking on update now in either place triggers a background job downloading the file and update the progress in UI in both the places (depending on where the user is).
- The user can update/download a max of 4 files simultaneously.

### Design:

- I have a GCM setup with WakefulBroadcastReceiver, that starts a IntentService to notify any updates.
- The update/download is a Runnable - DownloadRunnable.java
- A singleton class, MyDownloadManager has a static method startDownload() that starts the DownloadRunnable with a specific url.

### Problem:

- How do I update the progress in both notifications and activity while downloading the update?
- How do I extend the design to run concurrent downloads and update progress to the corresponding item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I would move the download task into a service.
2. I would not implement it myself, instead I would use the DownloadManager System service, see [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) and [usage example](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/).
3. In your UI you can query the download status inside a background thread, see this SO question: [Show Download progress inside activity using DownloadManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795872/show-download-progress-inside-activity-using-downloadmanager). Different to the solution I would use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

This allows you to perfom downloads in parallel. In the activity you can show the current progress by polling in a background thread, but I am not sure what you mean with the notification? The DownloadManager shows a notification when starts with downloading.

Your downloads will be much stabler instead of using an own implementation, since DownloadManager can deal with connection loss and will perform a retry.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Android's `DownloadManager`. This is the Download manager that the whole OS uses. U'll receive broadcast when the download is completed using `ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`.

Try this tutorial:

http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/