# How to calculate uploading task's percentage

Tags: java, android, upload, progressdialog

I have an `doFileUpload` method in `UploadAsync` class that `extends AsyncTask`.
I want to know how to calculate the uploading task's percentage from the following code to update a `ProgressDialog`  using `publishProgress(""+values)`

```
 private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null; 
        String exsistingFileName = "/sdcard/six.3gp";
        // Is this the place are you doing something wrong.
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String urlString = "http://192.168.1.5/upload.php";
        try
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                tv.append(inputLine);
            // close streams
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
            String str;            
            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
            }
            /*while((str = inStream.readLine()) !=null ){

            }*/
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done in my application

```
 long total = 0;
 int lenghtOfFile=connection.getContentLength();

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
```

You can see it here : [The Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: here  `HttpURLConnection connection = null;`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once, I used a cursor to track the bytes downloaded as mentioned here:
[Show Download progress inside activity using DownloadManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795872/show-download-progress-inside-activity-using-downloadmanager)