# How to show download process in activity on download manager android

Tags: java, android

i'm developing an app where users are able to download different content packages. For the download process i am using the DownloadManager class. Thats working fine so far.

My Question is how can i get the current progress of a running Download which was started with the DownloadManager. I know that there is the buildin Download Notification and so on. But for me it is necessary that i get the progress of the running download so i can use it to show the progress in a custom progressbar in my app. So far i was not able to retrieve the progress.

Is it even possible or am i just blind and can't find the solution.

and plese give me full code show i can understand

Hopefully someone can help me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795872/show-download-progress-inside-activity-using-downloadmanager

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-downloadmanager-example.html