# Alternative way to show download progress of DownloadManager

Tags: android, multithreading, android-download-manager

I'm trying to show the download progress of DownloadManager in percentage as shown in the notification bar.
I've read up some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795872/show-download-progress-inside-activity-using-downloadmanager).
However, the method provided is using the `Thread`.
As my understanding,`Thread` is not a good way.

Is there any alternative way to do the same thing? 
Or using Thread is just fine in this case?

Edit 1: 
Added in the code in my project.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {

                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                }

                final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

                ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(dl_progress) + "%");
                    }
                });
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: Please have a looks at this: http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-the-downloadmanager-to-manage-your-downloads.html

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon thanks for the advice and suggestion, I updated my question. 
Unfortunately, I cant find answer from the website =(. What I needed is the percentage of the download progress or the file size that not yet downloaded

Comment: You should definitely not use a Thread. There are several mechanisms for creating asynchronous communication like an AsyncTask or an IntentService. I would recommend use an AsyncTask for now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. May I know what is the main reason we should avoid using Thread?

Comment: Threads can block the UI and cause exceptions if you try to modify the UI from inside the thread, or any subsequent method invoked when exiting the thread.

Comment: Alright, thank you for all your assistance =) @QuintinBalsdon